# Piped command changes PID

Tags: logs, pipe

I created a (Debian) init Script for an executable Jar file:

```
[...]
NAME=NameOfMyShellScript
DAEMON="/usr/share/myApp/bin/$NAME"
USER="myUser"
PIDFILE="/usr/share/myApp/run/$NAME.pid"
EXTRA_ARGS=" -c $USER --background --make-pidfile"
[...]
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet $EXTRA_ARGS --pidfile $PIDFILE --startas $DAEMON --
[...]
```

My init script basically just invokes `start-stop-daemon` which executes a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
XNAME="hellofellow_1"
SCALATRA_ENV="development"
TMP_DIR="tmp/$XNAME/"
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx2024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
LOGFILE="logs/$XNAME.log"
PORT="8080"
JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.io.tmpdir=$TMP_DIR \
  -Dorg.scalatra.environment=$SCALATRA_ENV"

cd $(dirname $0)/../
rm -Rf $TMP_DIR*
exec java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar current/myJarFile.jar $PORT > $LOGFILE
```

This works so far, my applications runs and any output is written to `$LOGFILE`.

To enhance logging with rotation I then tried to to something like:

`exec java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar current/myJarFile.jar $PORT | multilog t s131072 n100 '!/bin/gzip' /my/log/dir`

Logging works perfect, but now `start-stop-daemon` writes the `PID` of `multilog` to  `$PIDFILE` and not the `PID` of my java process (so stopping does not work anymore).

Is there any "pipeline magic" that can be used to prevent that from happening? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your script with bash and use the process substitution construct to perform the logging. That way your “main” process will still be executed with the same process id as the shell was.

While you're at it, use an array for `JAVA_OPTIONS`, since it's a list of words. This way your script won't break even if `$TMP_DIR` or `$SCALATRA_ENV` contain shell special characters.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
XNAME="hellofellow_1"
SCALATRA_ENV="development"
TMP_DIR="tmp/$XNAME/"
JAVA_OPTIONS=(-Xmx2024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M)
LOGFILE="logs/$XNAME.log"
PORT="8080"
JAVA_OPTIONS=("${JAVA_OPTIONS[@]}" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=$TMP_DIR")
JAVA_OPTIONS=("${JAVA_OPTIONS[@]}" "-Dorg.scalatra.environment=$SCALATRA_ENV")

cd "$(dirname "$0")/../"
rm -rf "$TMP_DIR"/*
exec java "${JAVA_OPTIONS[@]}" -jar current/myJarFile.jar "$PORT" \
     > >(multilog t s131072 n100 '!/bin/gzip' /my/log/dir)
```